# Access build.xml in Jenkins via REST api

Tags: jenkins

Each finished build in jenkins has a build.xml file (in work/jobs/...BuildName.../builds/...BuildNumber... with a lot of info about the build. Is it possible to access that file using the rest api? I tried a lot of variations, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Jenkins itself for the documentation.
If you access the URL

```
http://SERVER/job/JOB/api/
```

You will see the way to use REST api, which can access all elements of your Jenkins (including parameters and logs from the build).

I hope this helps.